# Counting rows that satisfy a predicate in Django

Tags: sql, django

In Django I have a view in which I want to group by a non-primary key field and then for each group count the number of rows that satisfy a predicate. The code I tried is

```
funding_requests=FRNs.objects.filter(spin=spin).extra(
    select={"approved": "committed_amount > 0",
            "denied": "committed_amount=0"}
).values("funding_year").annotate(
    requested=Sum('orig_commitment_request'), approved=Sum('committed_amount'),
    disbursed=Sum('total_authorized_disbursement'), num_requests=Count("funding_year"),
    num_approved=Sum('approved'), num_denied=Sum('denied')
)
```

but I get the error message "Cannot resolve keyword 'denied' into field." I also tried

```
funding_requests=FRNs.objects.filter(spin=spin).values("funding_year").annotate(
    requested=Sum('orig_commitment_request'), approved=Sum('committed_amount'),
    disbursed=Sum('total_authorized_disbursement'), num_requests=Count("funding_year")
).extra(
    select={"num_approved": "sum(committed_amount > 0)",
            "num_denied": "sum(committed_amount=0)"}
)
```

and I do not get an error but `num_approved` and `num_denied` show up as blank on the page. Does anyone know how to get the number of rows that satisfy the given predicate for each grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the more annoying things about the new aggregate classes provided by django.  You can't use fields added with extra in annotations (except as groupings).  Unfortunately there isn't a good answer.

Pretty much the only answer I could provide would be to use a raw query and join the results in python

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not restrict the select statement's output by `values` before `annotate`.

Have you tried removing `.values("funding_year")` and including it at the end, if needed?

Comment: I had that statement there so that the sums would be counted per year, like in the examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#values